# MySQL select daterange data from two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

These is my table:

ut_period

```
id | month | year | name 
1  | 9     | 2013 | dddd
2  | 2     | 2017 | eeee
```

I want select rows witch in 2013-8 and 2018-9. So I wrote this query, but it is not successful:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ut_period` p  
WHERE `p`.`status` = 4 
  AND `p`.`year` >= '2013' 
  AND `p`.`mont` >= '8'
  AND `p`.`year` <= '2018' 
  AND `p`.`month` <= '9'
```

How can I do it?

Comment: what the reason for down vote?

Comment: **Don't quote/backtick your column & table names.**  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the easiest way to handle "year-months" is by multiplications -- essentially, number of months since some date:

```
select p.*
from ut_period p
where (p.year * 12 + p.month) between 2013*12 + 8  and 2018*12 + 9;
```

If you like, you can also convert these to numbers of the form YYYYMM, which makes it easier to put in the constant values for the range:

```
select p.*
from ut_period p
where (p.year * 100 + p.month) between 201308  and 201809;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the `BETWEEN` clause for the month and year**

([Documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between))

Also, you really ought to put the day, month and year into a single column - this is why MySQL has the date-related field types. Replace day, month and year with a single column with the DATE field type, then you can compare the dates much more easily.